# RemovedInDjango19Warning when using django-polymorphic

Tags: django

I started to use django-polymorphic in my project, which is based on Django 1.8.1.

It works fine, but I get the following warning:

```
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py:159: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class ContentType(models.Model):
```

I've plugged Polymorphic like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'polymorphic',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    ...
    'myapp1',
    'myapp2',
)
```

In myapp1/models.py I have my base model:

```
class MyBaseModel(PolymorphicModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    # some other fields
```

And in myapp2/models.py I have my derived models:

```
from myapp1.models import MyBaseModel


class MyDerivedModel1(MyBaseModel):
    # some fields


class MyDerivedModel2(MyBaseModel):
    # some other fields
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to put `polymorphic` after `contenttypes` in the list of installed apps.

Comment: At least official quick start guide suggests the following:

Update the settings file:

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'polymorphic',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
)

So I thought polymorphic should go before contenttypes. 

But actually putting polymorphic right before myapps seems to help :) Thank you!